# How to Calculate volume in pandas DataFrame cell?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, exec

I have a draframe that include a column with length, width and height as follow

| Volume |
| --- |
| 5.82x5.87x3.68 |
| 6.13x6.17x3.82 |
| 6.75x6.78x4.23 |

how can I calculate the volume in pandas and create a column to show the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['volume_calc'] = df['Volume'].str.split('x', expand=True).astype(float).prod(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
           Volume  volume_calc
0  5.82x5.87x3.68   125.721312
1  6.13x6.17x3.82   144.480422
2  6.75x6.78x4.23   193.585950
```